# Does iPad mini gets scratched easily without a case?

Tags: ipad, scratches

I got my iPad mini a Belkin case for protection, but it made the iPad mini twice as thick.  The iPad mini without the case is so slim and I love it, so i'm wondering if it can do without the case and not get scratched in the back and front easily..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe white one is more succeptible than black one. As far as the case, I picked up a clear case on ebay (shipped from Jersey) to go with my smart cover for $3.98 and it is pretty thin, maybe adds 2mm to the overall thickness. Just something to look at.

Comment: A smartcover for 3.98! Where can I get one like that? Thanks!

Comment: The smart cover was actually $7.98 (ebay from Hong Kong), $3.98 was for clear plastic back protector. To find it easily, go to ebay and search for "ipad mini smart cover orange". Order you results by price + shipping = lowest and scroll down to about $6.00 price range, you will see it. Go to seller's store, I believe other colors were available. It took about two and a half weeks to get to US, but it was well packaged and tracking# with China Post was provided. Hope this helps =]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and no, it really depends in what case you decide to use. Also without a case, it scratches amazingly fast.

Comment: I'm not sure what question the yes and no is answering.

Comment: Sounds more like you are saying no, without a case, it scratches too easily.